# Getting undefined when using action to find data using id [React-Redux]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-redux

I am using react redux to create a basic blogs CRUD app.
I have a blog list which have a read more button which when click should take me to that particular blog. I am trying to get into that particular blog using blog id and using useParam Hook. You can find my code below -

acion-creators - Actions

```
export const listBlog = (blogList) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({
            type: "list-blog",
            payload: blogList
        })
    }
}

export const addBlog = (blog) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({
            type: "add-blog",
            payload: blog
        })
    }
}

export const deleteBlog = (id) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({
            type: "delete-blog",
            payload: id
        })
    }
}

export const findBlog = (id) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({
            type: "find-blog",
            payload: id
        })
    }
}
```

reducer - blogReducer -

```
import blogs from "../data"
const reducer = (state=blogs, action) => {
    if (action.type === "list-blog") {
        return state
    }
    else if (action.type === "add-blog"){
        state.push(action.payload)
        return state
    }
    else if (action.type === "delete-blog") {
        state.pop(action.payload)
        return state
    }
    else if (action.type === "find-blog") {
        for(let i=0; i<=state.length; i++){
            if(state[i].id === action.payload){
                console.log(state[i])
                return state[i]
            }
            else{
                return "Blog not Found"
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        return state
    }
}

export default reducer
```

Blog page which should show that selected blog after clicking read more - BlogPage.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import { actionCreators } from "../State/index";

export const BlogPage = () => {

    const [blogId, setBlogId] = useState();


    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const actions = bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch)
    const params = useParams()
    

    useEffect(() => {
        setBlogId(params.blogId)
    },[])




    const handleEdit = (id) => {
        console.log(id)
        const blog = actions.findBlog(id)
        console.log(blog)
    }

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <h3></h3>
            <p>
                Body
            </p>
            <button className="btn btn-success my-3" onClick={() => handleEdit(blogId)}>Edit Blog</button>
            <button className="btn btn-danger mx-3">Delete Blog</button>
            <hr className="my-3"/>
            <button className="btn btn-primary">Like</button>
            <br /> <br />
            <h4 className="mx-3">Comments</h4>

        </div>
    )
}
```

In BlogPage.js I am finding the selected blog Id using useParam and using that in find-blog Action to find that particular blog in my state.
State is a list of blogs stored locally.

I am getting the id when I console.log the id of the blog but I am getting undefined when I try to use actions.findBlog()

It is showing undefined when I console.log the blog I find using the findBlog action.

Comment: ***Where*** exactly are you seeing an undefined `id` value? Or ***what*** exactly is undefined? Can you clarify what and where the issue is? Are you trying to return a value from the dispatched `actions.findBlog(id)` action creator? `findBlog` doesn't return anything. Any values from the Redux store should be accessed via the `useSelector` hook.

Comment: @DrewReese in my BlogPage.js you see I am console.logging blog which I have defined using const blog = actions.findBlog(id). I am getting undefined there. I have a list of blogs as state. Each blog has id, title and description. I am iterating through the list in my reducer and trying to match the id I am getting in my action payload and if I find the matching blog, I want to console.log that blog but I am getting undefined when I console.log(blog).

Comment: Also just FYI, all the action creator functions just need to return the action objects, no need to return a function that takes a `dispatch` arg, e.g. `export const findBlog = (id) => ({ type: "find-blog", payload: id });`.

Comment: I think you just missed to add `params.blogId` as a dependency array. Can you just correct writing useEffect on **BlogPage.js** like `useEffect(() => {setBlogId(params.blogId)}, [params.blogId])` and let me know whether it works or not?

Comment: Yeah, it worked. But I changed my method to do the process before. I used useSelector hook to select state and I accessed it directly without creating any action.